# Midpoint integration optimization

Tags: c, recursion, optimization, integration

I am working on approximating integration with midpoint integration in C and trying to optimize the time it takes to approximate with given n. I used recursion on integration dividing input n into two every time the function is called (so one of the two divided functions takes lower bound and midpoint and the other function takes midpoint and upper bound as inputs) until the difference between upper bound and lower bound becomes 1. When the difference is 1, I get the f(x) value and add everything up. Code looks like this:

```C
double integrate(function, range, lower, upper)
    if (upper - lower == 1)
        f(x)
    else
        integrate(function, range, lower, midpoint) +
        integrate(function, range, midpoint, upper)
```

From the first intution, I expected it to be faster with multiple processors if recursion is divided into four, instead of two, each time function is called, but it only slowed the approximation. So now I'm back with two recursions and don't know where to go. I tried using minimum number of operations.

Any related document or help would be appreciated a lot!

Comment: This can't be your code; you never compute `midpoint`.  And it never returns anything.

Comment: I ommitted many less important lines, the code was just to show the idea.

Answer (score 0):

Since you only call `f` when `upper-lower == 1`, you could just use iteration like

```
for (x = lower; x < upper; x++)
```

You don't show the specific relationship between `x`, `upper` and `lower`, so this might need to be tweaked, but you get the idea.

Comment: Okay I found out that iteration is faster than recursion. Would there be any more possible optimization?

Comment: Iteration is faster than *bad* recursion.

Comment: At least based on my recursion, iteration is faster.